# sql server - framework 4 - IIS 7 weird sort from db to page

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, sorting, .net-4.0

**SOLVED - look below at the end of the explanation**

I am experiencing a strange behavior when reading a resultset from database in a calling method. The sort of the rows is different from what the database should return.

My farm:
- database server: sql server 2008 on a WinServer 2008 64 bit
- web server: a couple of load balanced WinServer 2008 64 bit running IIS 7
The application runs on a  v4.0 app pool, set to enable 32bit applications

Here's a description of the problem:
- a stored procedure is called, that returns a resultset sorted on a particular column
- I can see thru profiler the call to the SP, if I run the statement I see correct sorting
- the calling page gets the results, and before any further elaboration logs the rows immediately after the SP execution
- the results are in a completely different order (I cannot even understand if they are sorted in any way)

Some details on the Stored Procedure:
- it is called by code using a SqlDatAdapter
- it has also an output value (a count of the rows) that is read correctly
- which sort field is to be used is passed as a parameter
- makes use of temp tables to collect data and perform the desired sort

Any idea on what I could check? Same code and same database work correctly in a test environment, 32 bit and not load balanced.

**SOLVED** - it was a problem in the stored procedure logic; in the last select I had an inner join towards a column, and the resulting sort (but only in the production db) was on that field, descending, instead that on the desired column. Modified the logic, now everything works. I still have to understand where is the real reason of this behavior only on one database and not against the other. Maybe some indexes...

Comment: Is there a difference in the SQL collation on your different SQL Server configurations, or perhaps Locale on Windows?

Comment: thanks Will, in the meantime I managed to understand the reason.